# Assignment in function signature

Tags: python, arguments

On function call the following code prints 10, but don't know the reason can any body please 
explain

```
def test(x=[]):    
    x.append(10)
    print x
```

Comment: because you are appending it

Comment: Actually, it prints `[10]` on the first call, `[10, 10]` on the second call, `[10, 10, 10]` on the third call, etc. See [“Least Astonishment” in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/395760).

Comment: what do you mean: prints 10 or test() returns 10?

Answer (score 2):

This is called a `default argument`

```
>>> def test(x=[]):
...     x.append(10)
...     print x
... 
>>> test()
[10]
>>> test([20])
[20, 10]
```

You specify the value to be taken, if the argument is not passed during the function call. So, if a value is given as a parameter, that is used. Else, the default value is used.

Answer (score 2):

it does not return 10 ... it simply prints it...

if you call it a second time it will print a list of 2 10's

a third time you will get a list with 3 10s

this is because a list is a mutable type and you are modifying the default argument with each call ... it does not start with a fresh list each call

Im not sure if this answers your question ...

Answer (score 0):

```
def test(x=[]):
```

Here you are defining a function `test` which takes a parameter called `x`. `x` is defined to take a default argument of `[]`, that is an empty list.

```
  x.append(10)
```

Here you append `10` to the empty list, which becomes `[ 10 ]`, that is a list which contains the number 10.

```
  print x
```

Here you print the list. That is why when you call `test()` you get

```
>>> test()
[10]
```

**The default argument is only evaluated once; the same value is passed to every call to `test()` in which you do not specify an argument explicitly.**

So if you call `test()` again you get:

```
>>> test()
[10, 10]
```

As you can see another 10 is appended to the original list.